# Why does discord.py block/buffer when awaiting an asyncio Queue?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, discord.py

The messages are sent in 'waves', i.e. nothing for a couple seconds and then ~5 nearly at the same time. I left out `token` and `channel`.

```
import discord, asyncio

class Bot(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self, q, channel):
        super().__init__()
        self.q = q
        self.channel_id = channel
        self.bg_task = self.loop.create_task(self.send_messages())

    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author == self.user or message.channel.id != self.channel_id:
            return
        print(message.content)

    async def send_messages(self):
        await self.wait_until_ready()
        channel = self.get_channel(self.channel_id)
        while not self.is_closed():
            msg = await self.q.get()
            await channel.send(msg)

from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

q = asyncio.Queue()
def f():
    while True:
        q.put_nowait("hi")
        sleep(2)
Thread(target=f).start()

bot = Bot(q, channel)
bot.run(token)
```

Weirdly, the `on_message` event seems unaffected, and also, replacing `msg = await self.q.get()` by

```
msg = "hi"
await asyncio.sleep(2)
```

seems to result in the expected behavior.

I'm not sure where things go wrong, so I kept the example more specific to Discord.

**Edit**

Expanding on the `asyncio.sleep` behavior, I have replaced the loop in `send_messages` by

```
if 0:
    msg = await self.q.get()
else:
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    if self.q.empty():
        continue
    msg = await self.q.get()
await channel.send(msg)
```

The `if` is just to toggle between the original and experiment.

Clearly, one would expect the `else` part to be at most as fast as the `if` part, however waiting for the queue to be non-empty seems to completely solve the issue.

I'm starting to think discord and a blocking asyncio Queue interact in unforeseen ways

On the other hand it seems that the `channel.send` is the blocking line, so maybe it also has something to do with rate.

Comment: That's just the internal workings of the discord api, asyncio itself isn't the problem

Comment: @LuM I suspected something like that, but then why doesn't the same apply to asyncio.sleep?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the rate limit for sending messages through Discord's API is 5 / 5 seconds.
That's why you're seeing 5 messages being sent at once and then a delay as the next messages are rate limited.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I think that's not the only problem. Please see my edit. The effect also occurs when sending messages less frequently (e.g. once every 10 seconds) or irregularly (which is the actual application)

Comment: Ah, this is possibly because [`asyncio.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#asyncio.Queue) is not thread safe. You should try using [`loop.call_soon_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.call_soon_threadsafe) or [`asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe).

Comment: Yes that would make sense. Just one small issue, I've replaced `msg = await self.q.get()` by `msg = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self.q.get(), self.loop).result()` but the result part seems to just block forever (even when the queue is nonempty) if I don't await something in the meantime. What am I missing?

Comment: Okay so obviously `.result()` blocks the event loop and hence `self.q.get()` can't run. Seems to me `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe` is only useful from another thread? Maybe it would help if I put the enqueuing part in the threadsafe function, however that's infeasible since it happens in a completely different part of the program. Any other idea that doesn't involve an extra thread?